# Cómo puedo hacer para que mi código en VSCode se muestre en el inspector de mi buscador

Tags: javascript, vscode, alert

estoy retomando con un curso de programación en JS y en uno de los ejemplos usan alert(). Cuestión que quiero escribir en VSCode = alert("Hola Mundo!"); refresco la pestaña del buscador en el que estoy trabajando y no aparece en el inspector. Ya probé en Chrome y Firefox
En el curso que estoy haciendo, hace un tiempo llegué a ver las functions y todos los ejercicios que había resuelto quedaron guardados en VSCode. Ninguno de esos ejercicios se muestra en el inspector.
Es medio boba la pregunta pero no me está permitiendo continuar y escribir código, si alguno tiene idea de lo que podría llegar a ser, agradecería la ayuda

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Has probado a borrar el caché?